# How to return a matching item from a list in Python

Tags: python

I want my function to return one of the short string in the list if it exists in another piece of long string.  How would you do it?

This is what comes up in my mind at the moment, but is there a better way to implement the func in Python?

```
>>> def func(shortStrList, longStr):
...     return shortStrList[[x in longStr for x in shortStrList].index(True)]
...
>>> func(['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'], 'PQRABCD')
'ABC'
>>> func(['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'], 'DEFPQRACD')
'DEF'
```

Comment: What do you expect the output of `func(['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'], 'ABCDEF')` to be?

Comment: Seems pythonic enough to me.

Comment: @DeepSpace I prefer it to return 'ABC'.  i.e. the first match

Comment: why not just use a for loop to traverse all shortStrList items, then 'If item in longStr: return item'? This is much direct.

Comment: What must your function return if there are no matches?

Comment: @RoadRunner Just raise an exception

Comment: Yeah I updated my answer @Porz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To consolidate the answers/comments, and to do a quick test on the performance of different answers...

```
>>> def timeTest(s, f):
...     t1 = time.clock()
...     for x in xrange(s):
...         f(['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'], 'PQRABCD')
...         f(['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'], 'PQRACDEF')
...         f(['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'], 'PGHIQRCD')
...     t2 = time.clock()
...     print t2 - t1
...
>>>
>>> def func1(shortStrList, longStr):
...     return shortStrList[[x in longStr for x in shortStrList].index(True)]
... 
>>> timeTest(10000000, func1)
18.4710161502
>>>
>>> def func2(shortStrList, longStr):
...     return next(s for s in shortStrList if s in longStr)
... 
>>> timeTest(10000000, func2)
26.1494262581
>>>
>>> def func3(shortStrList, longStr):
...     filter( lambda x: x in longStr, shortStrList)[0]
...  
>>> timeTest(10000000, func3)
26.1221138429
>>>
>>> def func4(shortStrList, longStr):
...     for s in shortStrList:
...         if s in longStr: return s
...  
>>> timeTest(10000000, func4)
8.78067844999
>>>
>>> def func5(shortStrList, longStr):
...     return [string for string in shortStrList if string in longStr][0]
... 
>>> timeTest(10000000, func5)
12.549210555
>>>
```

Seems like doing the loop (func4) as **Ekeyme Mo** suggested is quickest.  (though not sure if this can be re-written as one liner)

Just realised different methods maybe preferred if the length of the short string list differs.
While the simple loop still performs the quickest, next() performs quicker than list comprehension when the list is long.

```
>>> def timeTest(s, f):
...     sl = ['ABC'] + ['ZXYZ']*50 + ['DEF'] + ['RQDSF']*50 + ['GHI']
...     t1 = time.clock()
...     for x in xrange(s):
...         f(sl, 'PQRABCD')
...         f(sl, 'PQRACDEF')
...         f(sl, 'PGHIQRCD')
...     t2 = time.clock()
...     print t2 - t1
...     
>>> def func1(shortStrList, longStr):
...     return shortStrList[[x in longStr for x in shortStrList].index(True)]
... 
>>> timeTest(100000, func1)
2.14106761862
>>> 
>>> def func2(shortStrList, longStr):
...     return next(s for s in shortStrList if s in longStr)
... 
>>> timeTest(100000, func2)
0.867831158122
>>> 
>>> def func3(shortStrList, longStr):
...     filter( lambda x: x in longStr, shortStrList)[0]
...     
>>> timeTest(100000, func3)
3.19491244615
>>> 
>>> def func4(shortStrList, longStr):
...     for s in shortStrList:
...         if s in longStr: return s
...         
>>> timeTest(100000, func4)
0.629572839949
>>> 
>>> def func5(shortStrList, longStr):
...     return [string for string in shortStrList if string in longStr][0]
... 
>>> timeTest(100000, func5)
1.31148152449
>>>
```

Comment: plus one. Nice benchmark on consolidation of answers. Would surely help others.

Comment: Nice comparison. You might want to use [`time.clock`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock) for benchmarking as Python documentation suggest though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a generator expression with an if clause:

```
def func(shortStrList, longStr):
    return next(s for s in shortStrList if s in longStr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just keep it simple like this:

```
def func(shortStrList, longStr):
    try:
        return [string for string in shortStrList if string in longStr][0]
    except IndexError:
        return("No matches found")
```

Output:

```
>>> func(['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'], 'PQRABCD')
'ABC'
>>> func(['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'], 'DEFPQRACD')
'DEF'
>>> func(['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'], 'ABCDEF')
'ABC'
```

You can also do it this way without list comprehensions. This stops as soon as it finds the first solution.

```
def func2(shortStrList, longStr):

    result = ""
    for string in shortStrList:
        if string in longStr:
            result += string
            break
    else:
        return("No matches found")

    return result
```

Or even this way, which is the most simplest approach:

```
def func3(shortStrList, longStr):
    result = []
    for string in shortStrList:
        if string in longStr:
            result.append(string)
    else:
        print("No matches found")

    return result[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the matter of taste, you can use `filter` instead of list comprehensions if you like.

```
def func(shortStrList, longStr):
    filter( lambda x: x in longStr, shortStrList)[0]
func( ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JDSLDF'], 'PQRABCD')
# ABC
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You could use `e.__contains__` in place of the lambda function